# Can two-way binding be done with @dynamicOptions?

Tags: aurelia

I am using `@dynamicOptions` in my Aurelia application to facilitate wrapping a data grid that has a ton of options.

But now I need to have the equivilant of :

```
@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) doStuffCallback: () => void;
```

but if I do that I get an error.  I am guessing that `@dynamicOptions` fights with `@bindable`.

Is there a way to set up and (and set) a two way binding using `@dynamicOptions`?

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: just curious, why you have a two-way binding to a function call? I imagine it would not work regardless of dynamicOptions.

Comment: @huocp - I use that to be able to pass a callback to the users of my custom attribute. It usually works fine, but it needs two-way bindings.